# How to use @angular/fire in a Chrome Extension Manifest V3?

Tags: firebase, authentication, google-chrome-extension, angularfire, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I have just started building my first Chrome Extension (v3). It is a simple Angular app that uses @angular/fire for authentication and works seamlessly as a single page application.

I am able to run it as a Chrome Extension but there is an issue with returning logged in profiles. Angular Fire stores its JWT in localStorage so that if you return after logging in, usually you just get sent on without needing to re-login. However once the SPA runs as a Chrome Extension I have to log in every time it loads which is very painful.

Is there a way to expose localstorage to the SPA or can @angular/fire somehow be configured to use cookies instead of localStorage and sidestep around? (This is all new to me and I have yet to find anything in the docs so anyhelp is greatly apreciated.)

My manifest looks like this:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "My first sidebar Chrome extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "My first sidebar Chrome extension.",
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "service-worker.js"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_title": "My first sidebar Chrome extension"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "resources": ["*.woff", "*.woff2"],
      "matches": ["*://*/*"],
      "js": ["main.js", "polyfills.js", "runtime.js"],
      "css": ["styles.css"],
      "world": "MAIN",
      "run_at": "document_start"
    }
  ],
  "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"],
  "permissions": [
    "sidePanel",
    "tabs",
    "scripting",
    "storage",
    "webRequest",
    "cookies",
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "commands": {
    "_execute_action": {
      "suggested_key": {
        "default": "Ctrl+B",
        "mac": "Command+B"
      }
    }
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "assets/icons/ound_16.png",
    "48": "assets/icons/round_48.png",
    "128": "assets/icons/round_128.png"
  }
}
```

I have changed the permissions in the manifest but have been unable to trigger the login bypass that happens when run as a SPA.